# Поиск подходящего компонента в WinForms (С#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос: каким образом в C# WinForms можно реализовать компонент разворачивающегося текстового поля. То есть оно раскрывается по стрелочке, аналогично ComboBox, но в остальном ведет себя как обычное многострочное текстовое поле. В идеале, мне нужно сделать столбец таких компонентов в DataGridView. Не знаете, существуют ли готовые подобные решения?

Answer (score 0):

Многострочный ComboBox?
https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=c%23+multiline+combobox

Можно легко сделать самостоятельно: UserControl, в нем TextBox Dock=Fill и Button Dock=Right, сам popup сделать на ContextMenu или ContextMenuStrip, ну, и потом реализовать мелочи такие как правильная передача фокуса, он должен передаваться всему контролу как единому целому, а не полю или кнопке.